# Msg 207, Level 16, Invalid column name 'MH380'

Tags: sql-server, insert

I got an error from the insert statement.

The statement that I used to insert a tuple into the table is

```
insert into train values (103, MH380, 2000, 709)
```

By the way, the table was created by using the statement below:

```
(
TrainCode   CHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
TrainName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Capacity int NOT NULL,
Model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PKTrain PRIMARY KEY (TrainCode) 
)
```

Can someone please help? TQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MH380 appears to be a string, so you need to surround it in single quotes.

```
insert into train values (103, 'MH380', 2000, 709)
```

You may also want to check the other values too - they appear numeric but if you've declared their corresponding column types as chars or varchars (e.g. the train code?), you should really cast them as such by putting quotes around them too.

Also you might want to think about putting your column names into your INSERT statement, so the order of fields is explicit rather than implicit. Could save headaches later if your table gets altered!

Answer (score 1):

Per your posted table structure as below

```
(TrainCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL, TrainName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, Capacity int 
NOT NULL,Model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PKTrain PRIMARY KEY (TrainCode) )
```

Correct `INSERT` statement should be like below since except `Capacity` all other columns are of `VARCHAR` type.

`insert into train values ('103', 'MH380', 2000, '709'`)